# Android Clear drawn bitmap on canvas

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I've followed this tutorial (http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html) to capture a signature using canvas and it's OK.

I made some improvements to the code to save the signature as a Base64 string and it's OK too
I want to "reload" the string back to Canvas and it worked with the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(StringToBitMap(x), 0, 0, paint); // x = Base64 String PNG
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
```

I can see the loaded signature, I can draw something over it but I can't clear the loaded signature, it clears all my draws even if they are over the loaded signature but I can't clear the loaded signature. The code I'm using to clear is:

```
    public void clear() 
    {
        path.reset();
        invalidate(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void clear() {
    if (canvas != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```